# Cordova + ngcordova - Upload multiple images in a single request

Tags: javascript, ios, angularjs, cordova

I'm dealing with an IOS Ipad cordova app, it's a survey type app.

Once the user submits the survey, there are multiple images that I want to upload.

I'm using the ngcordova camera plugin to capture the images, I store the images as base64 DATA_URLS on $scope for the view to

I'm sending the server a HTML string for it to then create me a PDF of the HTML, including the images and then send it back to me as a base64 string.

This works for a small number of images, but there could potentially be 50-60 images uploaded when the survey is submitted, the base64 DATA_URLs of the images makes output HTML MASSIVE (as you'd expect).

This had led me to look at storing the captured images as FILE_URIs, it seems after researching that uploading multiple images as files isn't straightforward. I can't find any articles that solve the issue.

I've seen an approach that uses promises, to me this doesn't seem a good idea (due to the number of HTTP requests that would be fired), but I can't seem to find an alternative.

So how would I go about uploading the image files to my API?

Comment: Have you looked in the [Cordova Plugin Repository](http://cordova.apache.org/plugins/)?

Comment: the only way of sending multiple images at the same time is using the base64 string as you are doing. Using the FILE_URI and file transfer will send them one by one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have since used a workaround for this using the HTML5 Canvas element.

I simply iterate over the image files captured from cordova, convert them to blobs using the canvas API, then POST the collection of blobs to my API.